# fprintf writting 0D 0D 0A instead of 0D 0A in a txt file

Tags: c, hex, hex-editors

I'm trying to write a sample text using c, but my code is doing it wrong.
the code is below

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(){
FILE *ptr;
char c[8]={65,66,67,13,10,67,68,69};
int count;
ptr = fopen("write.txt","w");
for(cont = 0 ; cont < 8; count++){
     fprintf(ptr, "%c", c[count]);
}
return 0;
}
```

The text should be
ABC
CDE

But when I open it in a hex editor, this is what it display:

```
41 42 43 0D 0D 0A 43 44 45
```

**Edit:** I put wb instead of w and it works

Comment: You have the file open in text mode, and `\n` (ASCII `10`) gets translated to `\r\n` on write.

Comment: @dxiv I put wb and it works, thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Opening a file in text mode opens you up to having your data translated in certain ways, to comply with the requirements of the underlying environment.

For example, in Windows, opening a file in text mode may mean that the C concept of a newline character `\n` maps to and from the <kbd>CR</kbd><kbd>LF</kbd> character sequence in the file.

Hence, when you write the `13` (<kbd>CR</kbd>), it goes out as is. When you write the `10` (<kbd>LF</kbd>), that's the newline character `\n` and is translated to Windows line endings, <kbd>CR</kbd><kbd>LF</kbd>. That's why you're seeing `0D 0D 0A` in the file.

If you want to avoid this translation, just open the file in binary mode<sup>(a)</sup>:

```
ptr = fopen("write.txt", "wb");
```

---

As an aside, it's also a good idea to:

- check functions that *can* fail to see if they *do* fail (for example, `fopen` returning `NULL` or `fprintf` returning anything other than one (in this case));
- close files explicitly when you're done with them;
- let C automatically size your arrays where possible (`char c[] = {...}`); and
- use `sizeof(c)` rather than the "magic" number `8`.

---

<sup>(a)</sup> The relevant part of `ISO C11` is `7.21.2 Streams /2`:

> A text stream is an ordered sequence of characters composed into lines, each line consisting of zero or more characters plus a terminating new-line character. Whether the last line requires a terminating new-line character is implementation-defined. ***Characters may have to be added, altered, or deleted on input and output to conform to differing conventions for representing text in the host environment. Thus, there need not be a one-to-one correspondence between the characters in a stream and those in the external representation.***

But just keep in mind that even binary data may not go unmodified, as per `/3` in that same section:

> A binary stream is an ordered sequence of characters that can transparently record internal data. Data read in from a binary stream shall compare equal to the data that were earlier written out to that stream, under the same implementation. ***Such a stream may, however, have an implementation-defined number of null characters appended to the end of the stream.***

The only time I personally have ever seen that clause come into play is on the System z mainframes with fixed length record sizes that had to be padded out.